# Background Audio in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, background, avplayer

I'm trying to build an iOS App (iOS > 5.0). It should play music files when a timer, set by the user, ends. Here is my setup what if done so far:

- I use avplayer
- I've set Background Modes in my plist to "App plays Audio"
- in my appDelegate I have:

  ```
  NSError *sessionError = nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
  ```
- before a song is going to be played a set:

  ```
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&sessionError];
  ```
- i notify my application on "playerItemDidPlayToEnd", stop the player and tell other apps like the music.app to become active again

  ```
  _avPlayer = nil;
  NSError *sessionError = nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&sessionError];
  ```

This works fine. You can have your music app playing in background. My App starts to play a song the music app fades away. My song is played and if its finished the music app continues to play. But only as long as my app isn't in background.

In background I get the error:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560161140 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (OSStatus error 560161140.)"

Is it possible that both combinations of, playing in background (on custom events) and switching between f.e. music.app and my app in background isn't possible?

Here a the code of my player model: http://pastie.org/4830995

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be with background handling. You need to override this function on app delegate.

```
  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = 0;
 task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

}
```

your application will get killed after 6 minutes unless sound is played. If your user set timer for more then 6 minutes, what you could do is to play short quite sound every 5.5 minutes to keep you app alive and start new background task. Also you have to consider that lot of thing will not get executed in background. I did some stuff somewhat similar to what you are doing. What I did was created custom subclass of NSObject witch handled music playback and application expiration stuff. And made it a strong property on my delegate as lot of functions and notifications will not run on you VC in the background.

Although if you just want to play a sound this might not be the best approach. Maybe just sending local notification would do.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thx for your reply. This is good to know, wasn't aware of that. But i'm setting the timer on my tests to ~20 seconds. The Problem already appears there. It set the timer. Close the App. 20 seconds later the error appears.

Comment: hmm can you make sample project and post a link ?

Comment: Here is a link to demo project http://www.stringcode.co.uk/random/BackGroundSoundsDemo.zip this is how I handled playing sounds in the background. Point here is that if your application is not playing sound when enters background it becomes inactive. It also becomes inactive when you stop playing sound in the background. Therefore when you stop playning sound in background set timer for backGroundTimeRemaining - 0.10 and play some quick quite sound. this will reset you backroundTimeRemaining.Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your project. Works great. But actually you are using kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck to duck the audio when the app is in the background. If you remove the ducking and call [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&sessionError]; on audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying you will get my error in playData when [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:nil]; is called.

Comment: Ducking would have been a nice solution for my issue, but unfortunately its not possible to specify the ducking volume... for example to 0 :(

Answer (score -1):

Did you register your app to keep running in the background as an audio app? To do so, add the `UIBackgroundModes` key to your `Info.plist` file and set its value to `audio`.

Comment: yes, as mentioned above "ive set Background Modes in my plist to "App plays Audio" " but also i read in several threads the background modes doesn't have any effect since ios5 anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of that.